# C qsort not working as intended, erasing elements?

Tags: c, string, quicksort

i'm having a little trouble using the qsort available in C to sort an array of strings i have in a  struct of mine.

My code goes as follows:

```
typedef struct estrutura
{
    int sp;
    int numberOfEntries;
    int entriesSize;
    char* stack[26];
    char** list;
}*estrutura;


void createStruct (estrutura l, int numberEntries, int sizeEntries)
{
    l -> list = malloc (numberEntries * sizeof(char*));

    l -> numberOfEntries = numberEntries;
    l -> sp = 0;
    l -> entriesSize = sizeEntries;

    for (int i = 0; i < (l -> numberOfEntries); i++)
        (l -> list)[i] = malloc ((sizeEntries + 1) * sizeof(char));


}

int cmpstr(void const *a, void const *b) {
    char const *aa = (char const *)a;
    char const *bb = (char const *)b;

    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}

void addEntry (estrutura l, char* line)
{
    strcpy((l -> list)[(l -> sp)],line);
    (l -> sp)++;
}

void sortStruct (estrutura l)
{
    qsort((l -> list)[0], l -> numberOfEntries, (l -> entriesSize) * sizeof(char), cmpstr);
}

void printStruct (estrutura l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (l -> numberOfEntries); i++)
        printf("%s\n",(l -> list)[i]);
}

void freeStruct (estrutura l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (l -> numberOfEntries); i++)
        free((l -> list)[i]);

    free(l);
```

}

So my problem is: when i run a test in my main function:

```
int main ()
{

    estrutura example = malloc (sizeof(struct estrutura));
    createStruct(example,2,6);

    char* name = malloc (6*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(name,"A1234");

    char* otherName = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(otherName, "B1234");

    addEntry(example,otherName);
    addEntry(example,name);
    printf("/////BEFORE SORTING//////\n");
    printStruct(example);
    sortStruct(example);
    printf("/////AFTER SORTING//////\n");
    printStruct(example);

freeStruct(example);
```

}

The output that i get before the sorting is as expected:

```
"A1234"
"B1234"
```

But after the sorting, the output i get is:

```
"     " -> blank line
"B1234"
```

And this happens for every test i make. It just erases the first element and then doesn't sort at all. Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: 3rd argument to `qsort` function is size of each element in the array (in your case its `l->list`). So the 3rd argument is `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj im confused now, but when i do the malloc in the create function, doesn't that size change according to the size i indicate in the malloc?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj and the output remains the same tho. but thanks for the help so far!

Comment: first argument to qsort should be l->list, this is the location your pointers are stored,  and   the 3rd argument is sizeof(char*)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to sort an array with `N` entries of type `T`:

```
T *array = malloc(N * sizeof(*array));
```

Then your call to `qsort` looks like this:

```
qsort(array, N, sizeof(*array), t_cmp);
```

Your conparison function is:

```
int t_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const T *aa = a;
    const T *bb = b;

    // compare *aa and *bb
}
```

The pointers you receive are pointers to the array elements. They have the same type as the handle to the array, `array`. (If you have a fixed-size array as defined with  `T a[N]` these pointers have the same type as the array after it has decayed to a pointer. In both cases, that type is `T *`.)

---

In your case, the type `T` is `char *`. So:

```
l->list = malloc(l->numberEntries * sizeof(*l->list));
```

Then sort:

```
qsort(l->list, l->numberOfEntries, sizeof(*l->list), cmpstr);
```

with this comparison function.

```
int cmpstr(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    char *const *aa = a;
    char *const *bb = b;

    return strcmp(*aa, *bb);
}
```

(Instead of `sizeof(*l->list)` you can use `sizeof(char *)`, which would be `sizeof(T)`, the size of one element of the array, in the parlance used above.)

Comment: thank you a lot, it is outputting all the elements, but they are not being sorted tho

Comment: They are not? [I thought they were](https://ideone.com/eQ2tF5).